# Language & Char conversion to english keyboard

Tags: javascript, string, discord, discord.js, bots

So basically in short im making a bot on discord and there are a few words that I need to censor. No problem, except now users can simply use characters from keyboards that are not english, and bypass the censors. Is there a simple way I can take any string and convert its contents to english keyboard characters? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like DiscordJS is running on NodeJS - so here's what we can do.
Here is the example code posted on the website, but we can use it for your project.

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const client = new Discord.Client();

client.on('ready', () => {
  console.log(`Logged in as ${client.user.tag}!`);
});

client.on('message', msg => {
  if (msg.content === 'swearword') {
    msg.reply('naughty!');
  }
});

client.login('token');
```

With this code in place, you can use an API like [Google Translate API](https://cloud.google.com/translate/docs/reference/libraries/v2/nodejs) to take every word that is processed and pass it to it, and await a response.

Here is the [sample provided by Google](https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/translate/latest/index.html):

```
/**
 * TODO(developer): Uncomment the following line before running the sample.
 */
// const projectId = 'YOUR_PROJECT_ID';

// Imports the Google Cloud client library
const {Translate} = require('@google-cloud/translate').v2;

// Instantiates a client
const translate = new Translate({projectId});

async function quickStart() {
  // The text to translate
  const text = 'Hello, world!';

  // The target language
  const target = 'ru';

  // Translates some text into Russian
  const [translation] = await translate.translate(text, target);
  console.log(`Text: ${text}`);
  console.log(`Translation: ${translation}`);
}

quickStart();
```

If you combine the translation process along with msg.content you should get a swearword in another language.

Here's an example (I havent tested this but play around with it):
You will need Google API account / key etc. So please read their instructions on how to set it up.

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const client = new Discord.Client();

client.on('ready', () => {
  console.log(`Logged in as ${client.user.tag}!`);
});

/**
 * TODO(developer): Uncomment the following line before running the sample.
 */
// const projectId = 'YOUR_PROJECT_ID';

// Imports the Google Cloud client library
const {Translate} = require('@google-cloud/translate').v2;

// Instantiates a client
const translate = new Translate({projectId});

var translation = "";

client.on('message', msg => {
      // Translate msg.content
    
      // The target language (i think english is en, you need to check)
      const target = 'en';
    
      // Translates some text into English (i think)
      translation = await translate.translate(msg.content, target);
      
      if (translation === 'swearword') {
        msg.reply('naughty!');
      }
});

client.login('token');
```

Comment: I'm not too sure how Discord.js implementation works, but you'd need to install the Google Translate API module via node. If i get some extra time after work today i'll help you out if need be.

Comment: Im a bit new and confused, could you provide a sample that uses discord.js?

Comment: There you go @HrittikChatterjee , have fun learning programming :) itll be a great adventure. Let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: the thing is if someone sends a message like this: https://gyazo.com/abe2d68933ea77ad3f3a36ca3aed46ea it wont get translated to the english keyboard

Comment: Correct, for regular language translation it will work. You have a bigger problem to solve there, out of scope for this question. You may need to work on AI to determine which are swear words with those characters / which are not. That would take way too long to answer in a question on this site. Look into machine learning :) There might be a NodeJS machine learning lib somewhere.